# cron.daily not running automatically

Tags: bash, cron, debian

I've seen similar questions, but none of the solutions provided worked. All jobs within `/etc/cron.daily` are not running automatically. I'm on Debian 10.

Here's the file list:

```
me:~# ls -la /etc/cron.daily
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  7 16:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 root root 4096 Oct  9 11:00 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1478 May 28  2019 apt-compat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  314 Feb 13  2019 aptitude
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  355 Dec 29  2017 bsdmainutils
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1187 Apr 19  2019 dpkg
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 5142 Sep 28 23:34 imei
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  377 Aug 29  2018 logrotate
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1123 Feb 10  2019 man-db
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2628 Oct  7 22:55 nginx-ee
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  249 Sep 27  2017 passwd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  102 Jun 23  2019 .placeholder
```

All permissions and all file names are correct (filenames must not contain dots and files need the execution bit).

When executing `run-parts -v --report /etc/cron.daily`, all jobs are listed/executed:

```
me:~# run-parts -v --report /etc/cron.daily
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/apt-compat
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/aptitude
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/dpkg
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/imei
/etc/cron.daily/imei:
Everything is up to date.

run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/man-db
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/nginx-ee
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/passwd
```

As you can see, there's a job that produces some output. Could this be the issue? If so, is there any documentation that states that this is a problem?

Otherwise, I don't have any idea why it's not working as expected.

Comment: So what isn't running? You say it works when you run `run-parts -v --report /etc/cron.daily`. What is the actual issue? Is this not running automatically once a day? Is your cron service running? Do other crontabs work?

Comment: Does your `/etc/crontab` contain `25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )`?

Comment: @terdon I've updated the question. Yes, the problem is, that they are not running automatically, just upon manual execution. From what I can tell, other Jobs within `/etc/crontab` are running fine.

Comment: @laktak Yes, this entry exists.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: @NasirRiley Sure, but nothing.